# In TensorFlow, is it possible to use different learning rate for different part of the network?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

The use case I have in mind is to add more layers to a pre-trained network, and I would like to tune the entire net. However, I'd like the newly added layers to have a bigger learning rate than the existing one. Is it possible to do this in TensorFlow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set layer-wise learning rate in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945554/how-to-set-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a similar approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298326/freeze-some-variables-scopes-in-tensorflow-stop-gradient-vs-passing-variables)

Basically set a different var scope around each of the parts of the network you want to train with a separate learning rate then:

```
optimizer1 = tf.train.AdagradOptimzer(0.0001)
optimizer2 = tf.train.AdagradOptimzer(0.01)

first_train_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,
                                 "scope/prefix/for/first/vars")
first_train_op = optimizer1.minimize(cost, var_list=first_train_vars)

second_train_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,
                                  "scope/prefix/for/second/vars")                     
second_train_op = optimizer2.minimize(cost, var_list=second_train_vars)
```

Comment: Do I have to call both optimizer individually during training? `loss_value, _ = sess.run([reduced_loss, optimizer1])` and then `loss_value, _ = sess.run([reduced_loss, optimizer2])` ?

Comment: You can also do this loss_value, _ = sess.run([reduced_loss, optimizer1, optimizer2]) but you do need to run both optimizers for them to have an affect.

Comment: I wonder what will be the order in which optimizer1 and optimizer2 will be called in case `sess.run([reduced_loss, optimizer1, optimizer2])`? seems order is not guaranteed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844510/is-session-runfetches-guaranteed-to-execute-its-fetches-arguments-in-order