# Is it possible to get the objective function value during each training step?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

In the usual TensorFlow training loop, such as

```
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(num_steps):
        # ...
        train_op.run(feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

`train_op.run` returns `None`.

However, sometimes it's useful to collect intermediate results, such as the value of the objective or the accuracy.

Adding extra `sess.run` calls would require doing the forward propagation again, increasing the run time:

```
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(num_steps):
        # ...
        o, a = sess.run([objective, accuracy], feed_dict = feed_dict)
        train_op.run(feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

Is it possible to do this in TensorFlow in one go?

---

**Edit:**

People suggested

```
sess.run([objective, accuracy, train_op], feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

but the results depend on the execution order of the list elements:

```
[objective, accuracy, train_op]
```

which appears to be undefined -- [you get different results depending on whether CUDA is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43858891/1937197).

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If it did, can you select it as the answer?

Comment: I don't really understand why it didn't solve your problem. I can help further if you clarify.

Comment: Your attitude is not very cooperative, I consider withholding information as rude on this site. I am here to learn and I can't see the "serious" bug in my code, if you see it please disclose it without any condition. Thank you

Comment: forgive me but you behave really strange. I am not insulted, I just asked you a question and you still didn't answer it properly. So, again, what is the problem with my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Simply add you `train_op` to the list of nodes to be evaluated.

```
o, a, _ = sess.run([objective, accuracy, train_op], feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

Regarding the training step and its order in the evaluation, I made the following small experiment:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(x-1)
train_opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1)
train_op = train_opt.minimize(loss)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
x_val, _, loss_val = sess.run([x, train_op, loss])
# returns x_val = 1.0, loss_val = 0.5
```

The situation is more confused than I initially thought. What seems to be a given is that the order of execution of the fetches does not depend of their respective position in the list: `x_val` and `loss_val` will be the same independently of their position in the list.

However, as @MaxB noticed, their order of execution is not guaranteed. When running the above code on GPU, `x_val` is set to 0.0, the initial value. However, when running on CPU, `x_val` is 1.0, that is, the value *after* the update from `train_op`.

This configuration-dependant behavior could be limited to variables updated by training operations, as the experiment above suggests, but their is no guarantee coming from tf's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Two things: Is this guaranteed to execute the "fetches" in-order? Is this guaranteed to "share" the forward propagation rather than just running it 3 times?

Comment: (I asked about the execution order earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844510/is-session-runfetches-guaranteed-to-execute-its-fetches-arguments-in-order , but got no answers)

Comment: It will execute in an appropriate order all the nodes that are upstream of the nodes that are specified in your list, so that all of your nodes can be evaluated by the same propagation.

Comment: but they are not "upstream" -- you can calculate each without the other. I haven't found anything in the documentation specifying the order in this case.

Comment: I mean the nodes that are upstream of your `objective`, `accuracy` and `train_op` nodes -- basically everything that is needed for their evaluation but not more.

Comment: My point is that if train_op updates the weights before accuracy is calculated, this looks like a race condition of sorts.

Comment: **"loss is computed before train_op is called, but the value of x that is returned is that after the training step"** -- doesn't this seem inconsistent? I can't tell what rule, if any, TF is implementing here.

Comment: Yours is actually a GREAT example, because it demonstrates that this is UB: you get different results depending on CUDA or no CUDA!!! Didn't notice this, did you? :-)

Comment: Indeed. That's a bit scary. I'll add this to my post.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide as many ops as you want in `sess.run`. In your case you use `objective` and `accuracy`. Add your `train_op` there. Results of it is not needed so you can use `_`. Basically:

```
o, a, _ = sess.run([objective, accuracy, train_op], feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

P.S. regarding your comment, sess.run will not run the graph 3 times. ALso it will not necessarily even will run the graph once. It will figure out all ops that should be evaluated to evaluate 3 things you provided and will run all these ops (thus running a subgraph once)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm concerned about the execution order, as I mentioned in my comments to @user1735003

Comment: @MaxB I modified the answer

Comment: What if the weights are updated before the accuracy is calculated (race condition) Is there anything in the TF documentation saying this won't happen? I couldn't find it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844510/is-session-runfetches-guaranteed-to-execute-its-fetches-arguments-in-order

Comment: I think you should check your graph if the accuracy depends on the weights then they should be calculated before the accuracy

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The accuracy of a neural net on any mini-batch generally depends on its weights. Once the weights are updated, the accuracy may change. That's why the order matters.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using tf.control_dependencies with a duplicate variable `loss_after_train_op` for the variable `loss`. I built upon @user1735003's answer.

For example, if you are interested in finding out the value after the `train_op` "executes", you can add this code to your model definition:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
    loss_after_train_op = tf.nn.l2_loss(x - 1)
```

Then, if you just mention `loss_after_train_op` in a `run` call, it will give the expected result.

And, no, you can't just reuse `loss` again, because then you would have redefined it. Recall that `train_op` is already attached to the previous `loss` variable, so you would have lost track of that variable.

I also include a demonstration:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)

train_opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(x - 1)

train_op = train_opt.minimize(loss)
with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
    loss_after_train_op = tf.nn.l2_loss(x - 1)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
loss_val_1 = sess.run(loss)

print loss_val_1

x_val, _, loss_val, loss_after_train_op_val = sess.run([x, train_op, loss, loss_after_train_op])

print x_val, loss_val, loss_after_train_op_val
```

Output is

```
$ python test_control_dependencies.py
0.5
1.0 0.5 0.0
$
```