# Why we need to pass values using feed_dict to print loss value in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Below is small Tensorflow code

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[27]:

import tensorflow as tf


# In[28]:

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)


# In[29]:

# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b


# In[30]:

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


# In[31]:

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y))

# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)


# In[32]:

# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]


# In[33]:

# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# In[34]:

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)

  for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})

  # evaluate training accuracy
  curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})

  print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))


# In[ ]:
```

here in the for loop we have below code

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)

  for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})

  # evaluate training accuracy
  curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})

  print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

my question is when we run `sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})`  , `loss` also gets calculated , then why we need to pass feed_dict when want to retrieve loss value like below ? can anyone please help me understand this ?

```
 curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined 2 placeholders in your code: `x` and `y`. The `tf.placeholder` is a container which can be fed different values at each execution of the program.

When you use `tf.placeholder`, TensorFlow internally defines its computational graph using this container (placeholder). `sess.run()` runs this computational graph, but the graph by itself makes no sense because the placeholder containers are empty – they do not contain anything. Thus, whenever you use placeholders in your code, you are required to pass the values for these placeholders in your graph using the `feed_dict` parameter of `sess.run()`.

The advantage of placeholders is that the values you put in them for one execution of `sess.run()` are not remembered. That is, the second call of `sess.run()` will again have empty placeholders, and you will again have to put values into them through `feed_dict`. This is why you have to send values for the placeholders at every call of `sess.run()`.

A useful analogy might be to think of your TensorFlow computational graph as a physical machine – with inputs pipes (`x` and `y`) and output pipes (`loss`). The machine consumes data from the input pipes (so the data doesn't remain across multiple calls), and the machine also spits out stuff from the output pipes – if you didn't catch the output, you lost it. The machine (graph) doesn't *store* any value or result within it. It is just used to define a workflow which applies different operations on data.

Ops like `train` are levers of the machine, which when pulled *do* something within the machine. Now for the machine to do any work, you must put something in the input pipes. When you called `sess.run(train)`, the machine used up the data in the placeholders, computed loss (which it sent out through the `loss` output pipe, which you didn't catch) and modified its internal variables via backpropagation. Now the input pipes are empty again, and the old value of `loss` is lost! Thus, when you wish to calculate loss, you put in the data in the input pipes, and ask the machine to output the loss through the `loss` pipe.

You might be tempted to do this:

```
loss_value, _ = sess.run([loss, train], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
```

but unfortunately, TensorFlow gives [no guarantees](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) as to the [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844510/is-session-runfetches-guaranteed-to-execute-its-fetches-arguments-in-order) in which `sess.run()` evaluates its ops. So in the above line of code you won't know whether the `loss_value` returned is the loss before running the training op or after. The only way to do this is to first run the training op, then run the loss op in 2 separate calls to `sess.run()` as you have done in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `loss` is evaluated using `y` and `linear_model`.
Observe that:

- `y` is a placeholder, and
- the calculation of `linear_model` requires the placeholder `x`

So, once you have a placeholder, data will have to be passed-in using `feed_dict`.

By the way, running `sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})` invokes Gradient descent **for optimizing the loss function**.

While running `curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})` is for printing out the current value of the loss that has been optimizied after executing the train operation `train`.